# Cocoa Webview no longer plays Java applets in OS X 10.9 with latest Oracle plugin

Tags: java, cocoa, applet, webkit, 64-bit

I have a 64-bit Cocoa Webview application that used to play Java applets using the Oracle Java plugin under OS X 10.7.3 - 10.9.  At some point this stopped working, presumably with one of the updates to Webkit or the Oracle plugin.  I am running the latest version of the OS, the plugin, and Xcode, with all updates.  Everything is enabled (Java, plugins, etc.) for the Webview.

What happens now is that there is only blank space where an applet should appear, and there are no prompts or errors of any kind.  I am testing with applets at the Oracle Java website and at javatester.org.  I have tried a separate bare-bones Cocoa Webview app and it exhibits the same problem.  This occurs regardless of server, applet, or plugin settings in System Preferences.

I am aware of the recent increased security issues with Java.  I am able to get both Safari and Firefox to use the Oracle Java plugin on my system, but only if the browser preferences and the Oracle plugin preferences are managed properly.

For example, if I set Firefox to "always activate" Java applets, I still have to enable Java for browsers in the plugin preferences AND add the necessary servers to the whitelist there.  Safari lets you maintain the whitelist entirely within Safari if you want, but still requires the plugin preferences to be set to enable Java for browsers.  This is all inconvenient, but at least it is understandable and workable.

Interestingly, if the plugin preferences are NOT set to enable Java for browsers, then both Safari and Firefox act just like my own app, displaying only blank space for the applet with no prompts or errors.  This would seem to indicate that the plugin is somehow being prevented from loading in a standard Cocoa Webview.

Firefox is not Webkit-based, but Safari is.  My guess is that either Safari handles all its own Java plugin interaction and Webkit no longer supports it, or there is some Webkit-specific configuration that must be performed which I can find no reference to.  I can't try Chrome because it isn't 64-bit, which the Oracle plugin requires.  I can't find any other 64-bit Cocoa Webview apps that will play applets with the latest Oracle plugin either.

Anybody have any ideas on how to get this working, or on why it doesn't?  Anybody know of a 64-bit Cocoa Webview app other than Safari that will play Java applets using the latest OS X and Oracle plugin?

Comment: Hi, Have you got any solution for the problem? Actually I'm facing the same issue and requirement is to load Java Applet in WebView App. Thank you.